# Sublime Keymap - shift+space to go back one character in given context

Tags: sublimetext, keymapping

On my sublime-keymap file I already have this:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[ )'\"\\}\\]>: ]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

So, when my cursor is before any of these characters **)}]:;>** the shift+space will move the cursor to the right, jumping the character. This is very useful and already well known.

Now I was thinking that would be nice to have the inverse too. Imagine that I just jumped a closing } but then I remember that I still had something to type inside the {}. It would be great to be able to do shift+space again and get back inside the {}.

I was checking [this documentation](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/key_bindings.html) but everything I tried didn't worked.

Any help or ideas on this? Tks!

**EDIT : BASED ON CORRECT ANSWER:**

So, based on @skuroda's answer, this is what I came up with. For more information, read the comments below his answer.

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "[)'\"\\}\\]>,\\;:]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)'\"\\}\\]>,\\;:]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

The order of the code is important (preceding_text command must come before following_text one).

UPDATE: I think I found a much simpler and better solution for this:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
{ "keys": ["super+shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false} }
```

So, the context doesn't really matter here. `Shift + Space` will advance one character, `CMD + Shift + Space` will go back one character. Pure joy!

Comment: What have you tried? Did you see that the page you linked to is deprecated? [This](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) is the page you should be looking at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `preceding_text` key, so something like

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": false}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "[ )'\"\\}\\]>: ]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

If you have tried that, it's probably worth posting what you have already tried, so we don't repeat things you have already done (rather than just stating you have tried stuff). I also modified the regex slightly.

Comment: Thanks skuroda! This works just fine!
It seems the only thing I was missing was the regex that you changed. I even tried to change the regex a bit, but I don't know much about it.

Now I just need to play with it a little bit and see if I don't need to change anything on the regex.

Tks again!

Comment: You will need to make some modification of it. The regex `^[ )'\"\\}\\]>: ]` means look for a character from the beginning. In terms of the text following the cursor, this makes sense. However, for preceding text, you want the last character. To do this, I changed the regex to `[ )'\"\\}\\]>: ]$` the `$` forces the search of the last character, which again makes sense for preceding text. You can place both of the bindings into your key map file. The different context entries allow the proper command to be triggered for a given circumstance.

Comment: Thank you skuroda! I noticed that in cases like this }, (curly and comma), shift+space would keep jumping back and forth on the curly, so I needed to change the order of the code, so that "following_text" command would take precedence over the "preceding_text" one. Now it works like a charm! Even if you have a crazy thing like: "')}]:; it will keep moving forward, jumping the characters, until the last one. I'll edit my question adding what I have. I'm pretty happy with the results, thanks to you!

Comment: Glad you got something that worked. So you don't have to rely on ordering, you could add something like `{ "key": "following_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "^[)'\"\\}\\]>,\\;:]", "match_all": true }` to the context of the jump back. Note I'm not 100% sure this will work, but I tihnk it should. The regex must not match for the jump back to occur, which would again give the behavior you want.